# How do I save a select option list from foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a foreach loop which shows a option list with all the countries in it

```
foreach($countries as $cc => $name) {

echo '<option value="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</option>';
}
```

The selected option gets saved in the database. What i want to do is that if I go back to this page that it showed the already selected option from the database. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just put the selected attribute on the one which you want to select

```
foreach ($countries as $name) {
   if ($yourselectedValue == $name) {
       $selected = 'selected';
   } else {
       $selected = '';
   }
   echo '<option value="' . $name . '" '.$selected.'>' . $name . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work because $name is always the last name in the option list and not the selected one.

Comment: @kerv `$name` changes the value while loop is running so it'll eventually be the selected one and will set `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//$saved_option = get saved option or selected option

foreach($countries as $cc => $name) {
    if ($saved_option == $name) {
        echo '<option value="' . $name . '" selected="selected">' . $name . '</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: $name is always the last option of the select list so i cannot compare the the saved option and $name.

Comment: @kerv What makes you believe that `$name` is always the last option of the select list?

Comment: `$name` is not the last option. To check it print the value of `$name` into the loop. Every value of the `$countries` array will be printed. Just type `echo $name;` into the loop and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
$previousselect = database query;

foreach($countries as $cc => $name) {

echo '<option value="' . $name .'" '. ($previousselected == $name) ? 'selected' .'>' . $name . '</option>';
}
```

Or when you create your select object

```
<select name="arbitraryname" value="' . echo($previousselect); . '">
```

Sorry was just quickly typing it in wasnt going for syntax just the method

```
$previousselect = database query;

foreach($countries as $cc => $name) {

echo '<option value="' . $name .'" '. ($previousselect == $name ? 'selected' : '') .'>' . $name . '</option>';
}
```

should be the proper syntax

Comment: ehm that code won't work and giving a value to select wont make it work either.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the country id and store it in a variable

```
$query  = "SELECT country_id FROM Tablename WHERE YOUR_CONDITION";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$selectedOption = $row['country_id'];
}
else
{
$selectedOption = ''; // Your default selection of $cc
}
```

**Select box**

The below code displays all the options of country array. $cc will check with the database value ($selectedOption) and that country will get selected by default.

```
$Option = '';
foreach ($countries as $cc => $name)
{
    if ($cc == $selectedOption)
    {
        $Option .= '<option value="'.$cc.'" selected="selected">'.trim($name).'</option>';
    }
    else
    {
        $Option .= '<option value="'.$cc.'">'.trim($name).'</option>';
    }
}


<select name="country_id" id="country_id">
<?php echo $Option;?>
</select
```